# h2.bindAddress being ignored

Tags: kotlin, h2

I'm running a Kotlin & Spring Boot app using h2, and I'm doing the following:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    System.setProperty("h2.bindAddress", "127.0.0.1")
    System.err.println("Bind address set for h2")
    runApplication<Application>(*args)
}
```

I can see the code is running and the variable is being set, but I get my old DHCP address from yesterday in the error message:

`org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Connection is broken: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out: 192.168.0.5:63101" [90067-197]`

My DB URL is this:

`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:/tmp/testdb;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=TRUE;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;`

Any ideas why this is not working?  I deleted the database in `/tmp/testdb` but I am still getting the error.  How do I "reset" the bind IP address?

Comment: You found a work around ?